# action angle variable problem with limits of integration

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Good evening everyone, I'm having trouble solving this problem:
A particle moves in a vertical $xz$-plane as:

$$x=a(\sin{t} + t) ,\qquad z=a(1 - \cos{t}) \, .$$

It starts at $t = \pi / 2$.

I calculated the kinetic energy and is proportional to $\cos^2(t/2)$.
For the limits of integration of the action variable I should find the points where $T=0$, which turn to be $-\pi$ and $\pi$, however, it doesn't make sense to integrate from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ because, if the particle is released at $\pi/2$, it shouldn't have energy to reach a point higher than that.
Considering that, the integral should then go from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$... but in these points $T$ is not 0!

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Interesting: I get a kinetic energy $a^2 \cos ^2(t)+a^2 (\cos (t)+1)^2$ doesn't have any $\cos(t/2)$ in it. This notwithstanding, the curve you have is a cycloid and describes an isochronous pendulum (see https://catalogue.museogalileo.it/indepth/IsochronismPendulum.html) .  Depending from where it is launched, it will not "go higher" than its initial position.

Comment: My mistake, in the z component, it is a cosine instead of a sine, then you get a^2(cos^2+sin^2+1+2cost) which is a^2cos^2(t/2)